# How to take a value from html forms and operate a php function on it?

Tags: php, html, forms, built-in

How to have a php built in function work on a value taken from the user via html input.

```
<?php
$a="frm.txt.value";
$b=strtoupper($a);
echo($b);
?>

<form name="frm">
<table>
<tr>
<td>To Upper Case</td>
<td><input type="text"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: hope you want to apply validation with php learn from here https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp

Answer (score 1):

1. Put the name on the `<input>` not the `<form>`. Controls without names cannot be successful (i.e. included in the submitted form data).
2. Submit the form (by pressing enter in the input) … it is a good idea to include a submit `<button>` though.
3. Read the data from `$_GET['name_of_input']` in your PHP code

---

Asides:

- Don't use tables for layout
- Do learn how to use the `<label>` element

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a method GET or POST to the form when you create the form. Then you can get values using $_GET or $_POST

Comment: Since the input, in the question, doesn't have a name … you can't get values using `$_GET` or `$_POST` unless things you didn't mention in your answer are done.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning (y)